# Detect only RGB blue in image using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to detect the 3 circles of blue color on the image below, using C++ and openCV.

[image]

I use this code

```
int main(){
     Mat original=imread("img.jpg");
     Mat hsv;
     cvtColor(original,hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
     Mat bw;
     inRange(hsv,Scalar(110,50,50),Scalar(130,255,255),bw);//detects blue
}
```

This code **does** detect the 3 blue circles **BUT** also detect other blue points. I am thinking it has to do with the range I specified. Is there a way to detect only those RGB blue circles because I do not think there are any other points which are RGB blue in the image. **How can I detect only this color (255,0,0)??**

Comment: Then directly use inRange() on BGR colour space.

Comment: but what about the Scalar minimum and maximum values?will they be min=255,0,0 and max=255,0,0?

Comment: Yes........Like `inRange(original,Scalar(255,0,0),Scalar(255,0,0),bw);`

Comment: For the image you provided below you won't get accurate result with Scalar(255,0,0) as it has some Green value and G is not 255 every time. You can check both HSV and BGR value of pixel using the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257477/how-to-get-value-of-specific-pixel-after-converting-to-hsv/22265494#22265494)

Comment: try to split the image in the RGB color modell, and than work only on the blue channel, run houghcircles,  and detect what ever you want to

Comment: @Steph Just check this code works fine here `Scalar hsv_l(110,150,150);
 Scalar hsv_h(130,255,255);
 cvtColor(original,hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
 inRange(hsv,hsv_l,hsv_h,bw);`

Comment: @Haris you should post this as the answer!it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the image you provided  above, the below thresholds will work fine.

```
Scalar hsv_l(110,150,150); 
Scalar hsv_h(130,255,255); 
cvtColor(original,hsv,CV_BGR2HSV);
inRange(hsv,hsv_l,hsv_h,bw)
```

And you can easily find the HSV value of any pixel using mouse as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257477/how-to-get-value-of-specific-pixel-after-converting-to-hsv/22265494#22265494).

Also the HSV color wheel (below) might be helpful to choose any color and get it's HSV value.

[image: HSV Colour wheel]

Comment: Hey if you have a bit of time, can you have a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34170856/trying-to-detect-blue-color-from-image-using-opencv-and-getting-unexpected-resu). Actually I have tried to set quite a wide range for blue color, but I am probably missing somethign.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect the colour represented by (255,0,0) then this is the value you should specify when using the `inRange` function. Also, if you are interested in the RGB colour, then you don't need to convert your image to hsv.

Note that the [relevant page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20inRange%28InputArray%20src,%20InputArray%20lowerb,%20InputArray%20upperb,%20OutputArray%20dst%29) in the OpenCV docs says that the upper and lower bounds in the `inRange` function are inclusive - you can use the same value for both.

Some minor modifications:

```
int main()
{
    // Paint a blue square in image
    cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(100,100,CV_8UC3);
    cv::Scalar blue(255,0,0);

    img(cv::Rect(20,20,50,50)) = blue;
    cv::imshow("Original Image", img);


    // Detect this blue square
    cv::Mat img2;
    cv::inRange(img, blue, blue, img2);
    cv::imshow("Specific Colour", img2);

    cv::imwrite("Input.png",img);
    cv::imwrite("Output.png",img2);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Input.png**
A blue square drawn in an image

[image: Input.png]

**Output.png**
The blue square has been detected in this binary image

[image: Output.png]

Comment: thanks for this @Chris. But I still cant detect only those 3 blue circles.Actually,I have to detect those blue circles and then draw a contour around it.In all the size of the contours should be 3. Here is my full code http://pastebin.com/5PqQDXGX and here is the image http://i.imgur.com/p2jO5lf.jpg

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meanwhile?