# Cursor input from Video

Tags: python, c++, opencv, video, cursor

I'm trying to pass cursor coordinates from webcam video. But, I can't figure out how to do it.
I'm processing video using Python/C++ with OpenCV, along with a blob detection library for detecting blobs. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: please explain: "cursor coordinates from webcam video"

Comment: I did that using Qt + C++. If you want to work in Qt then I can help with this.

Comment: @Salman If you are trying to access cursor position on OpenCV window  you can find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257477/how-to-get-value-of-specific-pixel-after-converting-to-hsv/22265494#22265494